How to set Shipping Calculation in Salesforce Commerce App Store Object
I am trying to setup a store in Salesforce Commerce App, But it gives me below error when I try to add a zone

Only documentation I can find is : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.comm_set_up_native_shipping.htm&type=5
Also, the documentation states that after Spring24 the native shipping is already included, but I am not able to see those created for my store, Infact if I query there are no StandardShippingRate created(Which according to the documentaion should've been)
But there were records of ShippingConfigurationSet and ShippingRateGroup created. So, I deleted those and executed the whole code available in documentation again.
Now, that shows System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): AddressCountry, original object: ShippingRateArea: []
But how is this associate with AddressCountry, and is that even a Salesforce Object?
How can I set the Shipping Calculations, is there something I am missing or what exactly is needed to set the same?
